# jQuery/Bootstrap Portfolio only works with modal on desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, prettyphoto

I have combined the modal from this theme [blacktie theme](http://www.blacktie.co/demo/shield/)

with the filterable jquery gallery found here [filterable jquery portfolio](http://binarytheme.com/btlivedemos/28032014/filter-portfolio/index.html)

My problem is I have it working fine on desktop but not on tablet or mobile devices. I wanted the functionality of the filterable portfolio but with the popup category and modal of the first theme.

I have it loaded to a local server off my pc here [test site](http://spidey81.no-ip.org:8081/Shield/Shield%20Theme/#myModal). I think the problem is the filterable jquery portfolio uses prettyphoto to call on an "overlay" class that I didn't use in my markup. I used the grid mask classes from the first themes portfolio. Any ideas on how I can get this to work on mobile and tablet resolutions?

Thank You

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I think i may have figured it out. I tried adding another link to the modal using a portfolio image. so now my title pops up from the bottom of the image on desktop but now on mobile I can just click the image itself to make the modal appear.

Answer (score 0):

I wrapped one of my portfolio images with this and now it works when I press the image on mobile.

```
<figure>
                    <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="assets/img/portfolio/folio01.jpg" alt=""></a>
                        <figcaption>
                            <h5>WEB DESIGN</h5>
                            <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">View</a>
                        </figcaption><!-- /figcaption -->
                  </figure><!-- /figure -->
```